# Blocking Memory Queue

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, f#, queue

This is a FIFO blocking memory queue in F# to be used as a component in a logging library.

```
namespace Primitives

open System
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

type QueueOpResult<'T> =
    | Success of 'T
    | Failure of exn
    | Cancellation

type QueueOpCancelType =
    | Timeout of TimeSpan
    | WaitHandle of WaitHandle

module BlockingQueue =
    open System.Diagnostics

    type MemoryQueueSlot<'elem> = {
        mutable timestamp: int64
        mutable entry: 'elem
    }

    type QueueMetrics = {
        TotalReadWaitTime: double
        TotalWriteWaitTime: double
        AvgReadWaitTime: double
        AvgWriteWaitTime: double
        TotalReads: int64
        TotalWrites: int64
        TotalMessageQueueTime: double
        AvgMessageQueueTime: double
        TotalMessagePassthroughCount: int64
    }

    type CancelScope(cancType) =
        let mutable isDisposed = false
        let disposerAndWH =
            match cancType with
            | Timeout ts ->        
                let cancelWH = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset)
                let rec tim = new System.Threading.Timer(
                                (fun (o:obj) ->
                                    let ewh = (o :?> EventWaitHandle)
                                    ewh.Set() |> ignore
                                ), cancelWH, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)
                let res () =
                    tim.Dispose()
                    cancelWH.Dispose()
                tim.Change(ts, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan) |> ignore
                (res, cancelWH :> WaitHandle)
            | WaitHandle wh ->
                let res () =                                            
                    wh.Dispose()
                (res, wh)

        member __.WaitHandle = disposerAndWH |> snd

        interface IDisposable with
            member x.Dispose() =
                if not isDisposed then
                    isDisposed <- true        
                    (disposerAndWH |> fst) ()


    type MemoryQueue<'elem>(capacity) as self =
        let items : 'elem MemoryQueueSlot array =
            let timestamp = Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()
            Array.init
                capacity
                (fun _ -> { timestamp = timestamp; entry = Unchecked.defaultof<_> } )

        #if DEBUG
        let mutable totalSuccessReadWaitTime = 0L
        let mutable totalSuccessWriteWaitTime = 0L
        let mutable totalSuccessReads = 0L
        let mutable totalSuccessWrites = 0L
        let mutable totalMessageQueueTime = 0L
        let mutable totalMessagePassthroughCount = 0L
        #endif

        let mutable readIndex = 0
        let mutable writeIndex = 0

        let slotsAvailableWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.ManualReset)
        let itemsAvailableWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset)
        let readAvailableWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset)
        let writeAvailableWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.AutoReset)
        let disposingWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset)

        let elemPostedEvent = new Event<'elem>()
        let elemReadEvent = new Event<'elem>()

        let isEmpty () = (readIndex = writeIndex)
        let isFull () = ((writeIndex + 1) % capacity) = readIndex

        #if DEBUG
        let metrics_StartWrite () =
            Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()

        let metrics_WriteEndWait startWaitTime timestamp =
            Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            totalSuccessWrites <- totalSuccessWrites + 1L
            Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            totalSuccessWriteWaitTime <- (timestamp - startWaitTime)

        let metrics_StartRead () =
            Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()

        let metrics_ReadEndWait startWaitTime =
            let timestamp = Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()
            Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            totalSuccessReads <- totalSuccessReads + 1L
            Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            totalSuccessReadWaitTime <- (timestamp - startWaitTime)
            timestamp

        let metrics_ReadComplete endWaitTime timestamp =
            Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            totalMessageQueueTime <- (endWaitTime - timestamp)
            Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            totalMessagePassthroughCount <- totalMessagePassthroughCount + 1L
        #endif

        let waitAny whs =
            try
                match WaitHandle.WaitAny(whs) with
                | 0 -> Success ()
                | _ -> Cancellation
            with e ->                
                Failure e

        let asyncOpWait
            (wh: WaitHandle) cancelType =
            match cancelType with
            | Some cT ->
                use cScope = new CancelScope(cT)
                let whs = [| wh; cScope.WaitHandle; disposingWaitHandle :> WaitHandle |]
                waitAny whs
            | None ->
                let whs = [| wh; disposingWaitHandle :> WaitHandle |]
                waitAny whs


        let asyncOpWaitUntilCanWrite = asyncOpWait writeAvailableWaitHandle
        let asyncOpWaitUntilCanRead = asyncOpWait readAvailableWaitHandle
        let asyncOpWaitUntilHasSlots = asyncOpWait slotsAvailableWaitHandle
        let asyncOpWaitUntilHasItems = asyncOpWait itemsAvailableWaitHandle

        let postSync
            item
            cType =
            #if DEBUG
            let startWaitTime = metrics_StartWrite()
            #endif

            match asyncOpWaitUntilCanWrite cType with
            | Success () ->
                let rec waitAvailSl () =
                    if isFull () then
                        match asyncOpWaitUntilHasSlots cType with
                        | Success () -> 
                            waitAvailSl ()
                        | Failure e ->
                            writeAvailableWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore
                            Failure e
                        | Cancellation ->
                            writeAvailableWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore
                            Cancellation
                    else
                        let timestamp = Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()

                        #if DEBUG
                        metrics_WriteEndWait startWaitTime timestamp
                        #endif

                        Thread.MemoryBarrier()
                        let wi = writeIndex
                        let slot = items.[wi]
                        slot.timestamp <- timestamp
                        slot.entry <- item

                        writeIndex <- (wi + 1) % capacity
                        Thread.MemoryBarrier()

                        if isFull() then
                            slotsAvailableWaitHandle.Reset() |> ignore

                        itemsAvailableWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore

                        writeAvailableWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore

                        elemPostedEvent.Trigger(item)
                        Success ()

                waitAvailSl()

            | Failure e -> Failure e
            | Cancellation -> Cancellation

        let readSync            
            cType =
            #if DEBUG
            let startWaitTime = metrics_StartRead()
            #endif

            match asyncOpWaitUntilCanRead cType with
            | Success () ->
                let rec waitAvailIt () =
                    if isEmpty () then
                        match asyncOpWaitUntilHasItems cType with
                        | Success () ->
                            waitAvailIt ()
                        | Failure e ->
                            readAvailableWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore
                            Failure e
                        | Cancellation ->
                            readAvailableWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore
                            Cancellation
                    else
                        let timestamp = Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp()
                        #if DEBUG
                        let endWaitTime = metrics_ReadEndWait startWaitTime
                        #endif

                        Thread.MemoryBarrier()
                        let ri = readIndex
                        let slot = items.[ri]
                        let res = slot.entry
                        let timestamp = slot.timestamp
                        slot.entry <- Unchecked.defaultof<_>
                        readIndex <- (ri + 1) % capacity
                        Thread.MemoryBarrier()

                        #if DEBUG
                        metrics_ReadComplete endWaitTime timestamp
                        #endif

                        if isEmpty() then
                            itemsAvailableWaitHandle.Reset() |> ignore

                        slotsAvailableWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore   

                        readAvailableWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore                                 

                        elemReadEvent.Trigger(res)
                        Success (res, timestamp)

                waitAvailIt()

            | Failure e -> Failure e
            | Cancellation -> Cancellation

        let postAsync item cType =
            async {
                let! postResult =
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> postSync item cType)
                    |> Async.AwaitTask
                return postResult
            }

        let readAsync cType =
            async {
                let! readResult =
                    Task.Factory.StartNew(fun () -> readSync cType)
                    |> Async.AwaitTask
                return readResult
            }


        member __.ElementPosted = elemPostedEvent.Publish
        member __.ElementRead = elemReadEvent.Publish

        member __.TryGetMetrics () =
            #if DEBUG
            let (!) x = double(x)
            let (!!) x = (!x / !(Diagnostics.Stopwatch.Frequency)) * 1000.0
            Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            {
                TotalMessagePassthroughCount = totalMessagePassthroughCount
                TotalMessageQueueTime = !!totalMessageQueueTime
                TotalReadWaitTime = !!totalSuccessReadWaitTime
                TotalReads = totalSuccessReads
                TotalWriteWaitTime = !!totalSuccessWriteWaitTime
                TotalWrites = totalSuccessWrites
                AvgMessageQueueTime = !!totalMessageQueueTime / !totalMessagePassthroughCount
                AvgReadWaitTime = !!totalSuccessReadWaitTime / !totalSuccessReads
                AvgWriteWaitTime = !!totalSuccessWriteWaitTime / !totalSuccessWrites
            } |> Some
            #else
            None
            #endif

        member __.Count =
            Thread.MemoryBarrier()
            let wI = writeIndex
            let rI = readIndex
            if (wI >= rI) then (wI - rI) else (capacity - rI + wI)

        member __.PostBlocking(item, ?cancelType) =            
            postSync item cancelType

        member __.Post(item, ?cancelType) =
            let op = postAsync item cancelType |> Async.Ignore
            Async.Start(op)

        member __.PostAsync(item, ?cancelType) =
            postAsync item cancelType

        member __.ReadBlocking(?cancelType) =
            readSync cancelType

        member __.ReadAsync(?cancelType) =
            readAsync cancelType

        member __.Dispose() =
            disposingWaitHandle.Set() |> ignore
            disposingWaitHandle.Dispose()
            slotsAvailableWaitHandle.Dispose()
            itemsAvailableWaitHandle.Dispose()
            readAvailableWaitHandle.Dispose()
            writeAvailableWaitHandle.Dispose()

        interface IDisposable with
            member x.Dispose() =
                self.Dispose()
```

Example usage:

```
let makeProducer
    msgNum
    (q: BlockingQueue.MemoryQueue<_>) =
    async {
        for i = 1 to msgNum do
            let! pr = q.PostAsync(i)
            match pr with
            | Failure e -> Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message)
            | Cancellation -> Console.WriteLine("Cancellation")
            | _ -> () // do something after posting
        return ()            
    }

let makeConsumer
    (q: BlockingQueue.MemoryQueue<_>) =
    async {
        let mutable active = true
        while active do
            let! rr = q.ReadAsync(Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)))
            match rr with
            | Failure e -> Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message)
            | Cancellation -> active <- false
            | _ -> () // do something with read value
        return ()
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you avoided implementing this with a MailboxProcessor? I would think that would simplify the low-level thread and lock management and reduce or eliminate the need for mutables, although it could complicate collecting your detailed metrics. But then, maybe there's a specific limitation of MailboxProcessor that made it unsuitable for your use case - I'm just curious what that might be.

Comment: @JoelMueller
I don't like the fact that it automatically adjusts its capacity, as i'm concerned about memory consumption in the case some buggy producer posts absurd amounts of items. I also wanted to try and measure the whole thing, to see just how fast something like this could actually perform. It was also a good learning experience.